# Working with GPIOs in kernel module IOCTLs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, gpio

I have working with GPIOs in my kernel module, while I set or reset GPIOS from an IOCTL I got the following warning in my "dmesg" Log.

```
[11115.549204] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 5199 at drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c:2415 gpiod_get_raw_value+0x7c/0xb8
[11115.558267] Modules linked in: ariodrv(O) [last unloaded: ariodrv]
[11115.564570] CPU: 1 PID: 5199 Comm: ARIO_RMG Tainted: G        W  O    4.9.166.RMG.-00002-gcbd9807b6c03-dirty #13
[11115.574776] Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree)
[11115.581320] Backtrace: 
[11115.583816] [<8010b150>] (dump_backtrace) from [<8010b3fc>] (show_stack+0x18/0x1c)
[11115.591426]  r7:00000009 r6:600b0013 r5:80c1ae70 r4:00000000
[11115.597119] [<8010b3e4>] (show_stack) from [<803f51d4>] (dump_stack+0x9c/0xb0)
[11115.604380] [<803f5138>] (dump_stack) from [<80124878>] (__warn+0xec/0x104)
[11115.611367]  r7:00000009 r6:80a39e28 r5:00000000 r4:00000000
[11115.617050] [<8012478c>] (__warn) from [<80124948>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x28/0x30)
[11115.624653]  r9:8d696000 r8:7ea8cfa0 r7:0000000e r6:8d26e600 r5:8c1f9c54 r4:8c207f10
[11115.632434] [<80124920>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<8042fbb8>] (gpiod_get_raw_value+0x7c/0xb8)
[11115.641177] [<8042fb3c>] (gpiod_get_raw_value) from [<7f00cd78>] (device_ioctl+0x334/0x9f8 [ariodrv])
[11115.650428]  r5:8004d282 r4:7ea8cfa0
[11115.654034] [<7f00ca44>] (device_ioctl [ariodrv]) from [<80219c58>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0xa8/0x914)
[11115.662595]  r7:0000000e r6:8d26e600 r5:8ccc5bc0 r4:7ea8cfa0
[11115.668278] [<80219bb0>] (do_vfs_ioctl) from [<8021a500>] (SyS_ioctl+0x3c/0x64)
[11115.675618]  r10:00000036 r9:8d696000 r8:7ea8cfa0 r7:8004d282 r6:8d26e600 r5:0000000e
[11115.683477]  r4:8d26e601
[11115.686035] [<8021a4c4>] (SyS_ioctl) from [<80107960>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x48)
[11115.693645]  r9:8d696000 r8:80107b44 r7:00000036 r6:00000000 r5:768c611c r4:7ea8cf98
[11115.701504] ---[ end trace 7be84f1e05fd36af ]---
```

But if I set or get a value to a GPIO pin in another function, like init function of my module I don't get these warnings...

So the question is how exactly I should work with a GPIO pin in an IOCTL call?

This is part of my GPIO set IOCTL code:

```c
IOCTL_FUNC(...) {

....

case IOCTL_RMG_GPIO_SET:
            {
                ....
                //I have initialized the GPIO pin as output before, and assume my gpio pin number is 4.
                //int gpioNumber = 4;
                //int value = 1;
                gpio_set_value(gpioNumber, value);

                break;
            }
 ....
}
```

It doesn't matter either I get or set a value. If I use those GPIOs in an IOCTL call I got warning. But in other internal functions like `init_module()` or `module_release()` functions I can set and get these values without warning.

**EDIT 1:**

The problem I have is on GPIOs which are on my IOexpander (MCP23xxx series), This IOexpander works on i2c bus.
I don't have problem or any warning while using the GPIOs which are on my processor (iMX6DL).

**EDIT 2:**

@Tsyvarev and @0andriy Thank you guys, From [this link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/driver-api/gpio/index.html) I figured out `gpiod_get_raw_value_cansleep()` function is not what I need, Cause this function needs a GPIO descriptor to work and my kernel error was for that. But the functions `gpio_get_value_cansleep()` and `gpio_set_value_cansleep()` functions are the functions are suited for i2c IO expander.

So thank you for helping me, The working code is now:

```c
IOCTL_FUNC(...) {

....

case IOCTL_RMG_GPIO_SET:
            {
                ....
                //I have initialized the GPIO pin as output before, and assume my gpio pin number is 4.
                //int gpioNumber = 4;
                //int value = 1;
                gpio_set_value_cansleep(gpioNumber, value);

                break;
            }
case IOCTL_RMG_GPIO_GET:
            {
                ....
                //I have initialized the GPIO pin as output before, and assume my gpio pin number is 4.
                //int gpioNumber = 4;
                value = gpio_get_value_cansleep(gpioNumber);

                break;
            }
 ....
}
```

Comment: Have you check the line `drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c:2415` which the warning refers to? E.g. [this warning](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.223/source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c#L2418) has a quite descriptive comment in the line above it.

Comment: To the OP: seems your code and your warning is not aligned, i.e. warning from `gpiod_get_raw_value()`, while in the code you mentioned `gpiod_set_raw_value()`, though it doesn't discard what @Tsyvarev pointed out to.

Comment: @0andriy: "better to give a link to Elixir" - My link points to elixir, not sure what is wrong with it. As for choosing version (4.9.166), this is because I see in the error log the string `4.9.166.RMG.-00002-gcbd9807b6c03-dirty`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, indeed, but version is slightly different.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you, I have read the comments on the link you mentioned. So what did I do wrong? I don't really understand what did I wrong cause I used GPIOs exactly as other used them. Also I have edited my question, please take a look.

Comment: @0andriy Thank you, I have edited my question, looks like I don't have problems on processor GPIOs and problem is while I use MCP23xxx IOexpander. This IOexpander uses i2c bus.

Comment: If you trigger exactly this warning, then its comment "Should be using gpiod_get_raw_value_cansleep()" suggests to use `gpiod_get_raw_value_cansleep` instead `gpiod_get_raw_value`. Have you tried that? Note, that it is you who can find which exact warning is triggered because the warning message refers to the kernel sources on your machine.

Comment: @Tsyvarev When I use gpiod_get_raw_value_cansleep ( ) , I get this error" Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 000001f1" and it cause my application hangs.

Comment: Probably there are some other problems in your code. It is impossible to help with it knowing only information provided in the question post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev There is a problem in my code, As you said! But why when I use the processor GPIOs I don't have these warnings? And I only seem to have problem while I use the MCP23017 IOexpander! It is weird!!!

Comment: Have you ever read the description of the functions you use? `gpiod_get_raw_value` is intended for use with GPIOs which cannot sleep, `gpiod_get_raw_value_cansleep` is intended for use GPIOs which could sleep. So, different sort of GPIOs may require different functions to use them (and different scenarios).

Comment: I2C bus communication can sleep, you may not to call these GPIO functions in atomic context.

Comment: @0andriy So what can I do for these GPIOs? I also have problem on getting interrupts from these pins... where should I look for using those GPIOs for interrupts and for IO operations without encountering any warning?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I know it now! But in my kernel when I called the function you mentioned error occurred...

Comment: Repeating @Tsyvarev: *Probably there are some other problems in your code. It is **impossible to help** with it knowing only information provided in the question post.*

Comment: To your **EDIT 2**: `gpio_*()` type of functions are DEPRECATED. You should **not** use them. Something tells me that you need to use `libgpiod` instead of what you are doing. Or at least look at their source code along with kernel support to understand what has to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the linux source at the warning, it tells you:

```
* This function should be called from contexts where we cannot sleep, and will
* complain if the GPIO chip functions potentially sleep.
WARN_ON(desc->gdev->chip->can_sleep);
```

You should be calling gpio_get_value_cansleep